# How can i assign my JavaScript value to jsp expression?

Tags: javascript, jsp, struts

How can i assign my JavaScript 'x' value to  jsp expression. Below my JSP file code.

```
    <%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/tlds/struts-bean.tld" prefix="bean"%>
    <%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/tlds/struts-html.tld" prefix="html"%>
    
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript">
        var x=10;

        document.getElementById("bookid").value=x;
    </script>
    
  <% String value = x %>
```

Comment: You can't. JSP is executed on the server side before anything is sent to the client (browser).

Comment: This is what I'd known as happens before. It you assign a value in JSP the value is not defined yet. But later you define the value in JavaScript, but in JSP you can't get the value because it doesn't wait for the value which is actually defined. Maybe if you call the next time JSP is able to assign a value.

Comment: Okay Thank you both